# What is the fastest way of communicating from PC to a Controller using LabVIEW?

Tags: communication, labview, parallel-port

I am working on a project wherein I need to communicate 8 boolean outputs to the controller based on the result generated by a program built using LabVIEW on a PC.

I have discussed this with a few colleagues who suggest using a parallel port data-bus and use TTL signals to communicate to a micro-controller which will give maximum transfer speed.

I understand it being a cost effective solution but will it be fastest way to communicate with a micro-controller? Also, considering it being a legacy technology which limits its availability on standard PC's I have to buy an additional PCI-E card with parallel port interface.

Comment: I think this should be on a hardware forum. I don't think an LTP will be the fastest solution due to the legacy and buffers in between. For fast solution go to a dedicated PCI-express IO card. NI (amongst others) offers a range of these cards for affordable prices, see https://www.ni.com/nl-nl/shop/select/pxi-digital-io-module

Comment: You need to be more specific than *what's the fastest?*. What is the actual requirement? Is it a maximum latency (from the PC software requesting the transfer to the data arriving at the controller) or a minimum throughput (Mb per second)? You realise that software on a PC running a standard operating system is not deterministic, so you can never guarantee exactly how quickly an operation will happen anyway? We need more detail here.